# Running multiple system commands in parallel using a python Program

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I want to write a simple python program which would have a list of system commands that I need to run in parallel to speed up the execution. But also want to method to retry any command that may fail.

So for example if I have following commands:

```
["ls", "w", "echo 'Hello World'", "some-command-that-may-fail"]
```

So the final command that may fail must be rerun again (Note: Not all commands need to be re-run, just the one that failed)

I tried using `"subprocess"` library in python but am not able to figure out how to add the retry logic.
For context, I will be leaving my approach down here

```
exit_codes = [0]*len(commands)

processes = []

print("Executing commands")
for cmd in commands:

    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    processes.append(process)

for process in processes:
    if process.poll() is None:
        exit_code = process.wait()
    exit_codes[processes.index(process)] = exit_code
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fail logic you can use a try and except to catch an error with a command and use the continue function to rerun it.

```
    try:
        result = some_function()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}") #remove this line if you dont want to print it
        time.sleep(10) #modify this if you want to wait longer or shorter or not at all
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to add the retry logic,

I tried using the exit_codes list to get if the process had failed, but it turns out the process will always be successfully executed, but the command may or may not. So I have to get the error code of the command instead of the process. Once it get the returncode which indicates that the command has failed, I will be add it to a *retry_list*

```
 result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

 for line in result.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
   print(line)
        
 for line in result.stderr.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
   print(line)

 if result.returncode != 0:
   print("Command Failed!")
   retryList.append(command)
```

Now, a normal list wont work here as we are working with different subprocesses, thus we would use a threadsafe list.
The *multiprocessing.Manager().List(*) method is used to create a shared list object that can be accessed and modified by multiple processes in Python's multiprocessing module.
Following is the retry logic I have implemented.

```
while retryCount:
  processes = []
  if retryCount == 3:
    print("Running Command")
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run_command_sp, args=(command, retryList)) for command in transfer_commands]
  elif retryList:
    print("Performing Retry")
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run_command_sp, args=(command, retryList)) for command in retryList]

   for process in processes:
     process.start()
            
   for process in processes:
     process.join()

   retryCount -= 1
```